# Undesired effect on focusout and mouseover - jQueryUI's tooltip

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm using **jQueryUI's tooltip** and I get a strange behavior when `mouseover` or `focusout` events happen. If you try a lot of times, you'll see, including that the **tooltip** stops working.

```
<input id="test" type="text" title="." />

$('#test').tooltip({
    disabled: true,
    track: false,
    show: {
        effect: 'highlight'
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        var tipElement = $(this);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(ui.tooltip).hide();
            tipElement.tooltip('disable');
            tipElement.tooltip('close');
        }, 7000);
    }
});

$('#test').on('focusout', function () {
    $(this).tooltip("option", "content", 'texto.');
    $(this).tooltip('enable');
    $(this).tooltip('open');
    $(this).focus();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9sns/1/)

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: I think you're trying to do stuff that tooltip is isn't intended for. Tooltip generally assumes that it's going to handle focus events, as well as showing and hiding its element, exclusively. If you need different behavior, you might need to write your own custom logic.